# ipv6 route from one interface to another

Tags: linux, windows, routing, ipv6, ping

I have a Linux virtual machine running in windows. The linux virtual machine has routing table 
Kernel IPv6 routing table

```
Destination                    Next Hop                   Flag Met Ref Use If
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 1     3 enp0s8
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 1     3 enp0s3
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 4   963 tap0
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1  1003 lo
::1/128                        ::                         Un   0   5    27 lo
fe80::7433:9075:ba59:879f/128  ::                         Un   0   2     6 lo
fe80::e857:c33c:77b0:f516/128  ::                         Un   0   2    29 lo
fe80::e857:c33c:77b0:f517/128  ::                         Un   0   5  1120 lo
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 4    22 enp0s8
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 4    21 enp0s3
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 4  1865 tap0
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1  1003 lo
```

tap0 interface is connected to qemu and enp0s3 is connected to windows via Host-only Ethernet adapter. 
ifconfig on linux machine is

```
enp0s3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:85:4b:93  
          inet6 addr: fe80::e857:c33c:77b0:f516/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:118 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:34 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:12822 (12.8 KB)  TX bytes:5168 (5.1 KB)

enp0s8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:e2:b2:44  
          inet addr:10.0.3.15  Bcast:10.0.3.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::7433:9075:ba59:879f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:159 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:219 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:27600 (27.6 KB)  TX bytes:21958 (21.9 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:311 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:311 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:30827 (30.8 KB)  TX bytes:30827 (30.8 KB)

tap0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e6:d7:29:0d:a8:1e  
          inet addr:192.168.7.1  Bcast:192.168.7.255  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: fe80::e857:c33c:77b0:f517/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8579 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3108 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:994341 (994.3 KB)  TX bytes:288331 (288.3 KB)
```

Eventually I want to ping windows interface from my qemu which is ofcourse not working, but I am trying to break the problem in smaller steps, e.g.

- from within qemu, can ping tap0 (working)
- from linux, can ping ipv6 of enp0s3 from tap0 interface (Not Working)

> ping6 fe80::e857:c33c:77b0:f516 -I tap0

- After I get the above working I would ping windows interface from tap0 interface.
- And finally from qemu to windows.

Am i going the right direction ? Why the ping isn't working ?

Comment: The current versions of Windows block ping by default. So probably you'll have to make a change to the local firewall. If both machines are connected to the same LAN they will have Link Local addresses (FE80::) automatically that should enable communication within the LAN.